# How do I return the contents of a ResultSet as a map?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, java-8

I would like to know how I can return a result set from a query as a map. 
This is my query where 'nameCodesString' is a list of strings e.g. `('raul', 'peter', 'shawn')`:

```
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select n.CODE, l.VALUE"
                                + " from TNAME n join TPROPERTIES l on n.UIDPK = l.OBJECT_UID"
                                + " where n.CODE IN (" + nameCodesString + ")")) {
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            log.info("rs {}",rs);
            nameCode = rs.getString(1);
            displayName = rs.getString(2);
            Person.add(new PersonDTO(nameCode, displayName, ""));
        }
    }
}
```

The result should be a code and a value. I am not sure how I can do this all in one connection to the database.

Comment: What you are doing has nothing to do with prepared statements

Comment: Show me the value of 'nameCodesString'

Comment: It is something like: ('raul', 'peter', 'shawn'). And the second table contains the displayName.

Comment: Apparently, your actual question is how to convert a two-column `ResultSet` into a `Map`. Then, everything else in your question and title is obsolete and distracting. Neither the fact that the source is a `PreparedStatement` (used in a way counteracting its purpose), nor that you use the `IN` operator together with a list of strings has any relevance to the processing of the `ResultSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello that is my suggestion

```
 String req="select n.CODE, l.VALUE from TNAME n join"
 +" TPROPERTIES l on n.UIDPK      = l.OBJECT_UID "
 +" where n.CODE IN ?";
 PreparedStatement stmt=null;
 ResultSet rs=null;

 try{
     stmt=conn.prepareStatement(req);
     stmt.setString(1, nameCodesString);
     rs=stmt.executeQuery();
     while(rs.next()){
       nameCode = rs.getString(1);
       displayName = rs.getString(2);
       Person.add(new PersonDTO(nameCode, displayName, ""));
     }
  }
  catch(SQLException ex){
     System.out.println(ex);
  }
  finally{
     if(rs!=null){
           try{
               rs.close();
           }
           catch(SQLException ex){}
       }
      if(stmt!=null){
           try{
               stmt.close();
           }
           catch(SQLException ex){}
      }
     if(conn!=null){
         try{
              conn.close();
         }
         catch(SQLException ex){}
     }
  }
```

It is just my suggestion i hope it can be a tip for you!
Best regards...

Comment: I strongly recommend to learn about the [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html)…

Comment: And where is the map here?

Comment: i thought that person is map on the other hand i ask him to display all the code of the class.Thank

Answer (score 0):

I failed to understand how preparedStatements should be used. In the end I decided not to use them and stick to executing a query string:

```
Map<String, String> personDetails = new Hashmap();
try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
   Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select n.CODE, l.VALUE"
              + " from TNAME n join TPROPERTIES l on n.UIDPK = l.OBJECT_UID"
              + " where n.CODE IN (" + nameCodesString + ")")) {
       while (rs.next()) {
          nameCode = rs.getString(1);
          displayName = rs.getString(2);
          personDetails.put(nameCode, displayName); 
       }
}
```